# How to make this REST get method in Java?

Tags: java, authentication, rest

I have the following REST get Request that works successfully:

[image]

The result is a XML document that I then want to parse. I tried the same in Java:

I use the following code:

```
public void getRootService() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://localhost:9443/ccm/rootservices");
    httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream in = entity.getContent();
    String projectURL = XMLDocumentParser.parseDocument(in);

    System.out.println(projectURL);
    HttpGet getProjectsRequest = new HttpGet("https://localhost:9443/ccm/process/project-areas");
    getProjectsRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    getProjectsRequest.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
    getProjectsRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");


    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String projectResponse = client.execute(getProjectsRequest, handler);
    //String projectResponse = client.execute(getProjectsRequest, handler);

    System.out.println(projectResponse);

}
```

But how can I do the authentication? I tried to just add another header field for the value "Authorization" but then I don't get the same result.

Comment: What do you mean by doing the authentication? Do you mean doing client authentication from the server or populating the `Authorization` header on the request?

Comment: I have to authenticate my client at the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to create a `UsernamePasswordCredentials`, something along the lines of (untested);

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope("somehost", AuthScope.ANY_PORT), 
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
```

See http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html

Edit:
Just tried the following code and successfully called a REST service on our dev environment that is BASIC protected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
        new AuthScope("dev.*******.com", AuthScope.ANY_PORT), 
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("*****", "******"));


    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

    String url = "http://dev.******.com:18081/path/to/service/id.xml";

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String resp = client.execute(get, handler);

    System.out.println(resp);
  }
```

Comment: I tried this, but setCredentials doesn't accept UserNamePasswordCredentials.

Comment: Really? HttpClient v4? `UsernamePasswordCredentials` implements `org.apache.http.auth.Credentials` so should work....

Comment: Hmm I'm using Java 1.6. Do I have to add a jar to the build path?

Comment: Just noticed a wierd thing; the `HttpClient` interface doesn't mandate `setCredentials`, so the client type has to be `DefaultHttpClient`.

Comment: Yes but why does my setCredentials method not accept a UserNamePasswordCredentials? I'm using jre6.

Comment: `HttpClient` doesn't, but `DefaultHttpClient` does. Also, you mean `UsernamePasswordCredentials` not `UserNamePasswordCredentials`, right?

Comment: Ok. I copied now your code, and now it compiles. But nevertheless. I don't get the XML document. Instead the html code indicates that authentication is required.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly add `Authorization` header to `HttpRequestBase` (an abstract class for `HttpGet`, `HttpPost`, etc.)

This example shows how Basic Authorization value is made.

```
String unhashedString = userName + ":" + password;
String hashedString = Base64.encode(unhashedString); //This class doesn't exist, it's for demonstration purpose only.

HttpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + hashedString);
```

In the server, you will have to do the reverse (if you're doing your own implementation.

Comment: @Roflcoptr, successful, in what way? I have this code all over the place and it works for me.

Comment: When I use that I get html code from the REST service. But if i use the REST plugin in Firefox as in the picture above, i get the XMl docukemtn.

Comment: @Roflcoptr, have you checked on the server if you `Authorization` header exists on the request header?

Answer (score 1):

The way I implemented this is to use the session with a standard HTTP controller. They call a login URL with user and password posted and I authenticate the session. Once that's done then all following URLs simply check to make sure the session is authenticated.

Comment: Yes but the problem is I cant find an example for that.

Comment: Well, my example would be using Spring MVC, but I simply passed the request in on each of the method definitions. From that request, I get the session, and store the current date in the session.

Each additional call I also pass in the request, get the session and check the date. If it's null or too long ago, I throw an exception, otherwise I update the date and continue processing normally.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication mechanism supported will depend on which web server is used to host Rational Team Concert. The Apache Tomcat server uses basic authentication, whereas, WebSphere Application Server supports both basic authentication and form-based authentication.

You can view the detail description [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/10/programmatic-authentication-and-certificate-handling-for-rational-team-concert-2-0/)